# Get string between numbers using PHP

Tags: php

How can I adapt this function below to get string between numbers?

Function:

```
function getInbetweenStrings($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
   return $matches[1];
}
```

Example:

```
1448459casa48912687
010697046a-parede-verde698012
456902sim-senhora4401254
```

Output expected:

```
casa
a-parede-verde
sim-senhora
```

Thank you.
@edit: I don't want to remove all numbers, I need them! I just want grab string between.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to remove all numbers, I need them! I just want grab string between.

Comment: What is supposed to happen in the case of something like `12345number10-downing-street54321` ?

Comment: @CD001 is possible to detect only first numbers and last numbers? The middle numbers in this situation belongs to the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex, which looks for a minimal sequence (by adding `?` to `.*`) of characters between starting and trailing digits:

```
^\d+(.*?)\d+$
```

In PHP:

```
$strings = array('1448459casa48912687',
                 '010697046a-parede-verde698012',
                 '456902sim-senhora4401254',
                 '12345number10-downing-street54321');

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $between = preg_replace('/^\d+(.*?)\d+$/', '$1', $string);
    echo "$between\n";
}
```

Output:

```
casa
a-parede-verde 
sim-senhora
number10-downing-street
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oABhq)

Answer (score 1):

If the strings are different (ie: [foo] & [/foo])

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}



$fullstring = '010697046a-parede-verde698012';
$parsed = get_string_between($fullstring, '010697046a', '698012');

echo $parsed; // (result = a-parede-verde)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to remove all numbers, I need them! I just want grab string between.

Comment: The number will always change, I need a way to grab string between numbers that still always changing

Comment: then you're supposed to use `preg_replace('/^\d+(.*?)\d+$/', '$1', $fullstring)` which will grab the text between numbers i hope